# How to add google translate to comments

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I want to be able to have the ability to translate to comments only , is there any type of module I could use for this

Answer (score -1):

Use the [[Automatic] Comment Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/comment_translate) module

> Comment translation utilizes the Microsoft Translator to create translations of submitted comments on nodes that have existing translations available. Translated comments are placed in moderation for review.

Comment: Does this work , As it is seen to be unstable